# Solving a limit involving integration for $a$ and $b$

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

If $$ \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\int_0^x\frac{t^2dt}{\sqrt{a+t}}}{bx - \sin x}=1 $$ then find the value of $a$ & $b$.

My Attempt: I applied L'Hospital's rule and hence differentiated both the numerator and the denominator. To differentiate the numerator I applied Leibniz's rule and obtained the following
$$ \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{a+x}}}{b - \cos x}=1 $$

What should I do next to obtain the values of $a$ and $b$?

Comment: mmm... it doesnt seem that exists a solution for constants $a$ and $b$ from your second equation

Comment: @Masacroso The answer is given as a=4 and b=1

Comment: the problem that I see is that the second limit doesnt exists for $b\in[-1,1]$, and if $b>1$ or $b<-1$ then the limit is $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ respectively. Hence L'Hopital cant be applied for $b\in[-1,1]$, and $b\notin[-1,1]$ is not a solution.

Comment: If you rearrange to have $ \lim_{x \to \infty} (\int_0^x\frac{t^2dt}{\sqrt{a+t}})/(x)=b - (\sin x)/x $ , it is clear the RHS converges to $b$, but It would seem that the LHS diverges. ?

Answer (score 1):

It's obvious that $\sin x$ is not relevant to the limit, so we rewrite the problem as:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x} \int_0^x\frac{t^2dt}{\sqrt{a+t}}=b$$

Let's simply compute the integral:

$$t^2=(t+a)^2-2a(t+a)+a^2$$

$$\int_0^x\frac{t^2dt}{\sqrt{a+t}}=\int_a^{a+x} \left(y^{3/2}-2a y^{1/2}+a^2 y^{-1/2} \right) dy=$$

$$=\frac{2}{5} (a+x)^{5/2}-\frac{4}{3}(a+x)^{3/2}+2 a^2 \sqrt{a+x}-\frac{16}{15} a^{5/2}$$

Now we look at the powers of $x$ and despair, because after dividing by $x$ we still have positive powers which will go to infinity in the limit.

So the problem doesn't have a solution.